# Override equals() in Java

Tags: java, overriding, equals

I am attempting to understand how "equals()" works in Java. Especially in contrast to  "toString()". Here is an example that is throwing me off course.

---

```
public class Car
{
    String make, model;

    public Car( String model, String make )
    {
        this.make  = model;
        this.model = make;
    }   

    public String toString()
    {
        String str = "This is a car. ";
        str += "Make: " + make + " | Model: " + model;
        return str;
    }

    public boolean equals( Car c )
    {
        return ( make.equals( c.make ) && model.equals( c.model ) );
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Node 
{
    protected Object obj;
    protected Node next;

    public Node( Object o )
    {
        this.obj = o;
        this.next = null;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return obj.toString();
    }

    public boolean equals( Node n )
    {
        return ( this.obj.equals( n.obj ) );
    }
}
```

---

```
Car c1 = new Car("toyota", "corolla");
Car c2 = new Car("toyota", "corolla");

Node nC1 = new Node( c1 );
Node nC2 = new Node( c2 );

nC1.print();
nC2.print();


if( nC1.equals( nC2 ) )
    System.out.println("They are equal!");
else
    System.out.println("They are NOT equal!");
```

---

Here nC1.print() and nC2.print() behaves as expected. Prints:

```
This is a car. Make: toyota | Model: corolla
This is a car. Make: toyota | Model: corolla
```

However
nC1.equals( nC2 ), prints:

```
"They are NOT equal!"
```

In short the question is that I can override "toString()", but not "equals()". What am I missing? I presume there is a simple explanation for this behavior.

Answer (score 7):

I think you should keep the signature of the method as:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj)
```

---

**As a side note:** put `@Override` annotation within the method you want to override to make sure that you are overriding the right method, otherwise the compiler complains.

Answer (score 4):

The method signature is

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) { ... }
```

You can't change the parameter type as you attempted to do.  A useful pattern for equals in `class Foo`  is

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Foo) {
        Foo foo = (Foo)o;
        return <expression testing equality of foo and this> ;
    }
    return false;
}
```

For your example,

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o)  
{  
    if (o instanceof Car) {
        Car car = (Car)o;
        return this.make.equals(car.make) && this.model.equals(car.model);
    }
    return false;  
}
```

Comment: Your `equals` method violates the symmetric property if there are subclasses of `Car`. Example: `SubCar extends Car`, `car.equals(subCar)` is true while `subCar.equals(car)` is false. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29

Comment: Why would `subCar.equals(car)` be false?  `subCar.equals()` will be this method inherited, `car` is an instance of `Car`, so the proper comparison of `make` and `model` will be returned.

Comment: I just coded it. Both comparisons are `true` when `make` and `model` are `equal`.

Comment: If `SubCar.equals` did an `instanceof SubCar` check then symmetric would be broken. A more correct way is to use `getClass()` to check the class type.

Comment: Well, this never entered my head and I think for good reason. Defining an `equals` predicate in a subclass with semantics for the super is like using `goto`: an invitation to a future maintenance headaches, therefore really bad practice. I've never seen this in a lot of years of reading and writing code.

Answer (score 1):

Your method signature is `public boolean equals( Car c )`. Thus Java doesn't override the `equals(Object)` method; instead it **overloads** it.

Since the `equals()` method in `Node` is calling `Car.equals(Object)`, it uses a different implementation.

You should do this instead:

```
public boolean equals( Object o )
{
    Car c = (Car)o;
    return ( make.equals( c.make ) && model.equals( c.model ) );
}
```

Comment: +1 For the right implementation! However, I think you need to use `instanceof` just to avoid `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Thank you all for the helpful hints and comments. The code works as desired by replacing the equals(..) code in Class Car with the following:

```
public boolean equals( Object o )
{
    if( o instanceof Car )
    {
        if( make.equals( ((Car)o).make ) && model.equals( ((Car)o).model ) )
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```